# Prove $ 2<(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

How to prove that $ 2<(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}$ for every integer $n>1$. I was thinking by induction, it works for $n=2$ but then I couldn't move forward.

Comment: $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=1+n\times \frac{1}{n}+\ldots=1+1+\ldots>2$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show $\Big( 1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)^n>2\Longleftrightarrow$ To show $(n+1)^n>2n^n$

Note that, for $n>1$, $$(n+1)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}n^k>n^n+\binom{n}{1}n^{n-1}=n^n+n^n=2n^n\space\space\space\blacksquare$$

Answer (score 9):

Hint: Use the binomial theorem, look at the first two to three terms.

Comment: Okay for example the first two and last one may be sufficient: $1+\binom{n}{1}\frac{1}{n}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n^{n}}$

Comment: @MattiaMariantoni Really just the first two and then noting that there are more terms left, and they are all positive.

Comment: Ah! I overlooked this answer and posted the same thing, should I delete mine, sir.

Answer (score 5):

you can use  [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality)

> for every $ x>-1$ $$\\ { \left( 1+x \right)  }^{ n }\ge 1+nx$$

Comment: There is still the equal sign though.

Comment: no problem,because here  $n>1$

Comment: Then that needs to be stated. As written, this does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

A Calculus approach: Show that the expression is greater than $2$ for $n=2$ $$\left.\left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n\right|_{n=2}=\frac 9 4 > 2$$ then show that the expression is only increasing past $n=2$
$$ \frac{d}{dn}\left[ \left(1+ \frac 1 n \right)^n \right] = \frac{1}{n+1} \left( 1 + \frac 1 n \right)^n \left((n+1)\log\left(1 + \frac 1 n \right) - 1 \right) > 0 \quad \forall n $$

Comment: Why partial derivatives?

Comment: @Bernard I don't know. Sometimes I do that cause I think $\partial$ looks cooler that $d$. I'll change it.

Answer (score 3):

[Bernoulli's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) says
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n}{\left(1+\frac1{n-1}\right)^{n-1}}
&=\left(1-\frac1{n^2}\right)^n\frac{n}{n-1}\\
&\ge\left(1-\frac1n\right)\frac{n}{n-1}\\[9pt]
&=1
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$ is increasing and since $\left(1+\frac12\right)^2=\frac94\gt2$, we get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Approach using AM-GM Inequality

First we show that 
$$f(n)=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$$

is monotone increasing. To see this, apply the AM-GM inequality to the following $n+1$ terms
$$\left\{1,1+\frac{1}{n},1+\frac{1}{n},\cdots n\mbox{ times}\right\}$$

You get
$$\frac{1+n+1}{n+1} \geq \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{\frac{n}{n+1}}$$

Rearranging gives you $f(n) < f(n+1)$ since the terms in AM-GM are not equal.
Since $f(1)=2$, the result follows.

Answer (score 1):

By the Binomial theorem,

$$\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=1+\binom n1\frac1n+\cdots=1+\frac nn+\cdots$$ where the extra terms are positive.